# Using an emscripten compiled C library from node.js

Tags: node.js, clang

After following instructions on the [emscripten wiki](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html) I have managed to compile a small C library. This resulted in an a.out.js file.

I was assuming that to use functions from this library (within node.js) something like this would have worked:

```
var lib = require("./a.out.js");
lib.myFunction('test');
```

However this fails. Can anyone help or point me to some basic tutorial related to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that your `a.out.js` file is going to look like this

```
function myFunction() {
  ...
}
```

Not like this

```
function myFunction() {
  ...
}

exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

You need to write a build script that lists the tokens you want to publically export from each C program and appends `exports.<token> = <token>;\n` to the end of your file for each token.

Comment: After some research I found the solution on the emscripten wiki page '[Interacting with Code](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code)' , Combining the **exports.<token>** with the **Pointer_stringify** and **allocate** functions does the job

Answer (score 9):

Actually, all the functions are already exported.  Generated JavaScript contains following lines:

```
var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE = typeof process === 'object' && typeof require === 'function';
// …

if (ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE) {
  // …
  module['exports'] = Module;
}
```

If you got a function called `my_fun` in your C code, then you'll have `Module._my_fun` defined.

There are some problems with this approach, though.

Optimizer may remove or rename some functions, so always specify them passing `-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_main','_fun_one','_fun_two']"`.  Function signatures in C++ are bit mangled, so it's wise to `extern "C" { … }` the ones which you want to export.

Furthermore, such a direct approach [requires JS to C type conversions](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code).  You may want to hide it by adding yet another API layer in file added attached with `--pre-js` option:

```
var Module = {
  my_fun: function(some_arg) {
    javascript to c conversion goes here;
    Module._my_fun(converted_arg) // or with Module.ccall
  }
}
```

`Module` object will be later enhanced by all the Emscripten-generated goodies, so don't worry that it's defined here, not modified.

Finally, you will surely want to consider [Embind](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) which is a mechanism for exposing nice JavaScript APIs provided by Emscripten. (Requires disabling newest fastcomp backend.)